# addClass doesnt render until next click

Tags: jquery

Using jquery when i addClass in my code, i see that the class is added to the element but the element doesnt seem to render with the new class until the next click. ? Why

I have tried offsetHeight and i have tried setTimeout to apply the addClass after 1 second but they still dont render until the next click.
I have tried clicking a dummy button, but still doesnt render until user manually clicks anything on the page.

```js
function SetStatus(button) {
  if ($('#' + button.id).prop('value') == 'ALL') {
    $('.optionsbtn').removeClass('btn-bordered');
    $('.optionsbtnall').removeClass('btn-bordered');
    $('#tblData').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    return false;
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.optionsbtn').addClass('btn-bordered');
      $('.optionsbtnall').addClass('btn-bordered');
    }, 500)
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-bottom: -30px; margin-left: 10px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainCPHm$MainCPH$MainCPH$ServiceFiltersHF" id="ServiceFiltersHF" value="ALL">
  <button id="DoNothing" onclick="return false;" style="display: none;"></button>
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainCPHm$MainCPH$MainCPH$ALLbtn" value="ALL" onclick="return SetStatus(this);" id="ALLbtn" class=" btn btn-inverse btn-xs optionsbtn optionsbtnall" title="All">
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainCPHm$MainCPH$MainCPH$Pendingbtn" value="Requested" onclick="return SetStatus(this);" id="Pendingbtn" class="btn-primary btn btn-xs  optionsbtn" title=" Requested">
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainCPHm$MainCPH$MainCPH$Plannedbtn" value="Planned" onclick="return SetStatus(this);" id="Plannedbtn" class="  btn-info btn btn-xs  optionsbtn" title="Planned">
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainCPHm$MainCPH$MainCPH$Completedbtn" value="Completed" onclick="return SetStatus(this);" id="Completedbtn" class=" btn-purple btn btn-xs  optionsbtn" title="Completed">
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainCPHm$MainCPH$MainCPH$ReportedBtn" value="Reported" onclick="return SetStatus(this);" id="ReportedBtn" class=" btn-success btn btn-xs  optionsbtn" title="Reported">
  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainCPHm$MainCPH$MainCPH$CancelledBtn" value="Cancelled" onclick="return SetStatus(this);" id="CancelledBtn" class=" btn btn-danger btn-xs  optionsbtn" title="Cancelled">
</div>
```

In the function above, i would expect after 1 second the element to have the btn-bordered class (which it does when i inspect the element) but it does not render until the next click ?

I should say that when i inspect the button on the page it does indeed have the class 'btn-bordered' but the button does not reflect the style until a click occurs on the page, given the class of the button changes, the code seems sound, but could something else be preventing the browser rendering the class until the next click ?

Comment: can you please add your HTML

Comment: Add now, thanks Nick

Comment: Could you reproduce it on JSFiddle? Don't forget to use the generated HTML code, without ASP elements.

Comment: I should say that when i inspect the button on the page it does indeed have the class 'btn-bordered' but the button does not reflect the style until a click occurs on the page, given the class of the button changes, the code seems sound, but could something else be preventing the browser rendering the class until the next click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it , and here is the demo [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y3w8o5vp/8/)

```
function SetStatus(button) {
  if ($('#' + button.id).prop('value') == 'ALL') {
    $('.optionsbtn').removeClass('btn-bordered');
    $('.optionsbtnall').removeClass('btn-bordered');


  } else {

      $('.optionsbtn').addClass('btn-bordered');
      $('.optionsbtnall').addClass('btn-bordered');

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks andrew, thats what i had to begin with, i added the timeout to try to delay the change by a second.

Comment: I ran the above fiddle and added a setTimeout to the else part of the if statement, everything works fine

Comment: if my answer helped you please mark it as answered , i hope it works now

Comment: Thanks both, something else on the page must stop the addclass being applied until the next click - is that likely ?

Comment: Try removing the Datatable line and see if that causes the problem and have tou tried as I wrote the code

Comment: Hi Andrew,yes the code works on its own, but not on the page ( although i do see the class being added to the element in F12 but it doesnt actaully render til the next click, so presumably my code is good ... just something is preventing the render ?